# Count maximum consecutive repeated non-NA values grouped by another variable in dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr, count, rle

I would like to determine the maximum count of consecutive repeated non-NA `Valor` values for each `ADM2_PCODE`. Therefore, the idea is to group by `ADM2_PCODE`, filter out the NA values, calculate for each `Valor` value the highest count of consecutive cases, and select the maximum occurrence between them.

Example dataframe below:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
                              1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986,
                              1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986), ADM2_PCODE = c(1100015, 1100015, 1100015, 1100015, 1100015, 1100015, 
                                                                                  1100016, 1100016, 1100016, 1100016, 1100016, 1100016,
                                                                                  1100017, 1100017, 1100017, 1100017, 1100017, 1100017), 
                     Valor = c(NA, NA, 30, 30, NA, NA,
                               90, 10, 90, 10, 10, 10,
                               30, 20, 30, 40, 30, 60), geometry = c("MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...", "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...",
                                                                     "MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Input:

```
 df
# A tibble: 18 x 4
    Year ADM2_PCODE Valor geometry                      
   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                         
 1  1981    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 2  1982    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 3  1983    1100015    30 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 4  1984    1100015    30 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 5  1985    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 6  1986    1100015    NA MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 7  1981    1100016    90 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
 8  1982    1100016    10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
 9  1983    1100016    90 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
10  1984    1100016    10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
11  1985    1100016    10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
12  1986    1100016    10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.0495 -1...
13  1981    1100017    10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
14  1982    1100017    20 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
15  1983    1100017    30 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
16  1984    1100017    40 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
17  1985    1100017    50 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
18  1986    1100017    60 MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.0495 -1...
```

Output expected:

```
ADM2_PCODE max_consecutive_values 
       <dbl>  <lgl>    
1    1100015 2 
2    1100016 3 
3    1100017 1
```

Comment: Hi Ronak. There are 4 10's, but only 3 are consecutive. The idea is to select the most consecutively repeated value, not overall most repeated. Does it make sense?

Comment: The confusion is on my side, I'm sorry about this. The input and the code to generate them were not identical, with 90 and 10 mixed up. Now I edited it properly and the `1100016 ` should read as: `90, 10, 90, 10, 10, 10`. So the most repeated consecutive value would be 10, 3 times. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` `rleid` to keep track of consecutive values you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Valor)) %>%
  group_by(ADM2_PCODE) %>%
  mutate(grp = rleid(Valor)) %>%
  count(grp) %>%
  summarise(max_consecutive_values = max(n))

#  ADM2_PCODE max_consecutive_values
#       <dbl>                  <int>
#1    1100015                      2
#2    1100016                      3
#3    1100017                      1
```